# How to delete a oracle table using Oracle.jl?

Tags: oracle, julia

I am trying to delete a table using Oracle.jl,as follows:

```
import Oracle

global const dbHost = "localhost";
global const dbClientType = "thin";
global const dbName = "xe";
global const dbPort = "1521";
global const dbUserName = "ava";
global const dbUserPassword = "ava";
global const conn_str="//"*dbHost*":"*dbPort*"/"*dbName;

conn = Oracle.Connection(dbUserName, dbUserPassword, conn_str);

String txn_drop_query = "DROP TABLE ava.txn PURGE";
Oracle.execute(conn, txn_drop_query);

Oracle.close(conn);
```

But, getting the following error:

```
julia> include("/root/ibs.jl")
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: extra token "txn_drop_query" after end of expression
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /root/ibs.jl:13
 [2] include(::String) at ./client.jl:439
 [3] top-level scope at REPL[1]:1
in expression starting at /root/ibs.jl:13
```

Please guide me in deleting a table using Oracle.jl.

Comment: What exactly do you have in line #54 in `/root/ibs.jl`?

Comment: line 54: String txn_drop_query = "DROP TABLE ava.txn PURGE";

Comment: looks like you need to remove "String" from it. Since Julia is dynamically typed

Comment: It should be just `txn_drop_query = "DROP TABLE ava.txn PURGE";`

Comment: what is the explicit type of txn_drop_query?

Comment: You shouldn't specify strings type in Julia language: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/

Comment: highly recommend you to read the Manual parts of Julia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String txn_drop_query = "DROP TABLE ava.txn PURGE";
```

That is wrong syntax in Julia. It doesn't support to define variable with type before variable name.
Just specify it as

```
txn_drop_query = "DROP TABLE ava.txn PURGE";
```

or if really want to specify type:

```
txn_drop_query::String = "DROP TABLE ava.txn PURGE";
```